# React.js: How to append a component on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm new to React and I'm puzzled on something kind of basic.

I need to append a component to the DOM after the DOM is rendered, on a click event.

My initial attempt is as follows, and it doesn't work. But it's the best thing I've thought to try. (Apologies in advance for mixing jQuery with React.)

```
    ParentComponent = class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor () {
        this.addChild = this.addChild.bind(this);
      }

      addChild (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#children-pane").append(<ChildComponent/>);
      }

      render () {
        return (
          <div className="card calculator">
            <p><a href="#" onClick={this.addChild}>Add Another Child Component</a></p>
            <div id="children-pane">
              <ChildComponent/>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    };
```

Hopefully it's clear what I need to do, and I hope you can help me attain an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As @Alex McMillan mentioned, use state to dictate what should be rendered in the dom.

In the example below I have an input field and I want to add a second one when the user clicks the button, the onClick event handler calls handleAddSecondInput( ) which changes inputLinkClicked to true. I am using a ternary operator to check for the truthy state, which renders the second input field

```
class HealthConditions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      inputLinkClicked: false
    }
  }

  handleAddSecondInput() {
    this.setState({
      inputLinkClicked: true
    })
  }


  render() {
    return(
      <main id="wrapper" className="" data-reset-cookie-tab>
        <div id="content" role="main">
          <div className="inner-block">

            <H1Heading title="Tell us about any disabilities, illnesses or ongoing conditions"/>

            <InputField label="Name of condition"
              InputType="text"
              InputId="id-condition"
              InputName="condition"
            />

            {
              this.state.inputLinkClicked?

              <InputField label=""
                InputType="text"
                InputId="id-condition2"
                InputName="condition2"
              />

              :

              <div></div>
            }

            <button
              type="button"
              className="make-button-link"
              data-add-button=""
              href="#"
              onClick={this.handleAddSecondInput}
            >
              Add a condition
            </button>

            <FormButton buttonLabel="Next"
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              linkto={
                this.state.illnessOrDisability === 'true' ?
                "/404"
                :
                "/add-your-details"
              }
            />

            <BackLink backLink="/add-your-details" />

          </div>
         </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to add hundred of InputField through clicking?

Comment: @kabrice keep a list in state and then map on that list and show that hundred inputfields

Comment: @youneskhanbaba but doesn't that affect apps performance when react rerender all of those components when another component is added?

Answer (score 136):

Don't use jQuery to manipulate the DOM when you're using React.  React components should render a *representation* of what they should look like given a certain state; what DOM that translates to is taken care of by React itself.

What you want to do is store the "state which determines what gets rendered" higher up the chain, and pass it down.  If you are rendering `n` children, that state should be "owned" by whatever contains your component.  eg:

```
class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    numChildren: 0
  }

  render () {
    const children = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
      children.push(<ChildComponent key={i} number={i} />);
    };

    return (
      <ParentComponent addChild={this.onAddChild}>
        {children}
      </ParentComponent>
    );
  }

  onAddChild = () => {
    this.setState({
      numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1
    });
  }
}

const ParentComponent = props => (
  <div className="card calculator">
    <p><a href="#" onClick={props.addChild}>Add Another Child Component</a></p>
    <div id="children-pane">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  </div>
);

const ChildComponent = props => <div>{"I am child " + props.number}</div>;
```

Comment: Great answer!  I'd only add add the .bind(this) to this.onAddChild to ensure it can call this.setState.

Comment: This worked for me (with @ewindsor 's addendum)! Awesome solution.

Comment: One thing I learned is that `children` is a react keyword. That is, I renamed the `children` `const` defined inside of `AppComponent`, but, regardless, I still needed to call `{this.props.children}` inside `ParentComponent`.

Comment: @ewindsor oops!  I typed that up pretty quickly lol thanks for that - fixed

Comment: @jayqui yes - I could have made that clearer.  You can rename the const all you want, but if you pass them like you would put a `<span>` inside a `<p>`, then they are accessed via `this.props.children`.  If you pass them like you would an `href` attribute to an `<a>` tag, then you access them via `this.props.[attribute name]`.

Comment: The key here is the {this.props.children}  inside the parent component. This example makes it a bit confusing because the name of the array containing the children elements is also called children. Even if we push new components to an array called `dogs` we need to render {this.props.children} in the Parent component

Comment: you can use jquery but your code is a mess. React JS already handle all the view part of your page (MVC architecture).