# How to append table on button click with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need, when a user clicks on a button, that React renders a table under said button. How to do it?

```
let a = '';

if (this.state.text) {
  a =
    <table border="1" width="40%" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <th>Ячейка 1</th>
        <th>Ячейка 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ячейка 3</td>
        <td>Ячейка 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
} else {
  a = ''
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js: How to append a component on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905988/react-js-how-to-append-a-component-on-click)

Answer (score 1):

Create a button within your component that has the onClick event listener. Then, adjust the state variable where you control the table rendering accordingly (in your case, the `text` state variable).

Finally, within the render function, conditionally render the table based on the state.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // State variables
    this.state = {
      // Controls table rendering
      text: true
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* Conditionally rendering table */}
        {
          this.state.text ? (
            <table>Table</table>
          ) : ''
        }

        {/* Button with onClick event listener */}
        <button onClick={() => this.setState((state) => {
          return { text: !state.text }
        })}>Button</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```