# is there a way to append a component using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

Basically i would like the user to click a button which will add a `<Message />` component to the page. and they can keep clicking the button and more `<Message />` components will be created.

Pseudo Code

```
render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.addMessage}></button>
        <Message />
        //basically a new message component would spawn here so it would look like this if the person clicked the button 3 times

        <Message /> 
        <Message /> 
        <Message /> 

    );

}

addMessage = () => {
   create new Message component
}
```

Comment: Hint... every click adds to an array in state and you then map that array in the render() and each iteration creates a new `<Message/>`

Comment: As @charlietfl says, each action by the user sets a new array with one extra item in it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js: How to append a component on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905988/react-js-how-to-append-a-component-on-click)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a state object to do what you want. For example,

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const wasClick = (data) => {
    setMessages([...messages, data]);
}
```

and then in render function

```
messages.map(message=><Message message={message}/>)
```