# How to add a new div on button click with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a new input on button click in one of my React components.
What's the most elegant way to do it?

This is an abstraction of my code:

```
const addDivs = (type) => { ??? }

export default function Form() {

handleSubmit(e) {...}

return ( 
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<div><textarea rows="4" placeholder="Write about something here..." /></div>
//New divs should go here

//Adds a textarea
<button onClick={() => addDivs(textarea)}>Add textarea</button>
//Adds an upload field
<button onClick={() => addDivs(upload)}>Add image</button>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </form> ); 
}
```

I want to keep the buttons underneath the inputs.

How's the best way to do this?

Comment: So you want to insert your divs under the textarea but the button should be directly below the textarea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js: How to append a component on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905988/react-js-how-to-append-a-component-on-click)

Comment: Do you want a new input or a new div?

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to create 2 states, one for each button, they will have the number of the divs needed for each tag.

```
const [textAreaNo,setTextAreaNo] = useState(0);
const [uploadNo,setUploadNo] = useState(0);
```

then after your buttons you can call the (addDiv) function, but u will have to create 2 different functions for each button, or just make one function and inside the function it will return `upload` or `textArea` depending on the passed parameter.

then finally you need to use `map` like this

```
{[...Array(textAreaNo)].map(e=>(
    <div> textbox <div>
  ))}
```

and on your button we will just increment the states above like

```
 <button onClick={()=> setTextAreaNo(textAreaNo+1)}>AddDivs</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to be able to add multiple text areas. A way I would do it, is to create a state item that knows how many text areas you need, and then a function that increases this number on the onClick(). You will also need a function that returns the text box item. Something like this:

Class Component:

````js
this.state = {
    numberOfTextAreas: 0
}

const textAreas = () => { //<---------a function like this

for (let i = 0; i < this.state.numberOfTextAreas; i++) {
    return (
        <div>
           <textarea rows="4" placeholder="Write about sompething here..." /> 
        </div>
    );
}
}

const addDivs = (type) => { ??? }

export default function Form() {

handleSubmit(e) {...}

return ( 
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<div><textarea rows="4" placeholder="Write about something here..." /></div>


//New divs should go here
{textAreas} //<---- Add this here.


<button onClick={() => this.setState({numberOfTextAreas + 1})}>Add textarea</button>
//Adds an upload field
<button onClick={() => addDivs(upload)}>Add image</button>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </form> ); 
}

```
````

Then you'll just want to do the same with the other types you are wanting to create.